# Encapsulated 2-dimensional array versus plain version - access speed

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, heap-memory

This question is the continue of this one: [2-dimensional array on heap, which version is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598062/2-dimensional-array-on-heap-which-version-is-faster)

I have defined something like that:

```
class Array
{
    double *data;
    int X;
    int Y;

public:
    Array(int X, int Y, double init = 0) : X(X), Y(Y)
    {
        data = new double [X*Y];
        for (int i=0; i<X*Y; i++)
            data[i] = init;
    }
    ~Array() { delete[] data; }
    double *operator[] (int x) { return (data+x*Y); }
};
```

I want to have the speed benefit of an continuous array with the readability of a 2-dimensional. I thought `class Array` would do this, with

```
Array arr(1000,1000);
arr[x][y] = n;
```

being (nearly) same fast as plain version

```
double *arr = new double [1000*1000];
arr[x*1000+y] = n;
```

since `operator[]` is defined `inline`.

But the plain version is much faster and the encapsulated one is only a little bit faster as the true 2-dimensional one `double **arr; ...; arr[x][y] = n;` **not really true, see Edit2**

Is this normal? I am compiling on VC++ 2010 with optimizations on.

And please no answers with using `vector`, I know of this possiblity but I am interested in the deeper reasons for this behaviour...

**Edit**:

I've read the comments, that my `class Array` makes 2 lookups and I should use a direct 1 lookup and return reference to double. I've tried this and there is *no* speed improve, it's exactly the same.

And I don't really see why my class does 2 lookups:

```
Array arr(1000,1000);
arr[x][y] = n;
```

should be inlined to:

```
(arr.data+x*arr.Y)[y] = n;
```

and further:

```
*((arr.data+x*arr.Y)+y) = n;
```

what is exactly the same as:

```
arr.data[x*arr.Y+y] = n; // the proposed 1 lookup access
```

Am I wrong?

**Edit2**:

I timed again and noticed, that `double **arr; arr[x][y] = n;` solution has different times ranging from 1:47 min to 2:10 min - in a random style.

All other solutions:

1. the encapsulating `class Array` like above
2. with `double &operator() (int x, int y)` like proposed
3. with plain `double *arr; arr[x*Y+y] = n;`

are actually *same* fast around 1:44 min and always constant.

Comment: "... a little bit faster as true 2-dimensional one" : You assessment of that is quite the opposite. A dynamic array of pointers to dynamic array(s) of data is anything *but* a "true 2-dimensional array". The only thing it shares in common with a *real* 2-dimensional array, `Type data[N][M]` is syntactic sugar, and a disassembly of the generated opcodes will show you this. You're correct that a contiguous region with single-lookup is going to be faster; your code simply isn't doing that (yet). I'm confident some of the answers will demonstrate this.

Comment: Regarding your edit about the expansions being the same: actually yes the way you've set it up they should be as you're overloading changes the meaning of the brackets. So indeed your class Array solution should be about as fast as all the single lookup solutions, with the double ** way being slower as you found. It might be worth looking at your profiling tests, as if you aren't doing much with your arrays then the compiler might be optimising out most of the test leading to an inaccurate result (or if optimisations aren't on then the test is useless for the real world).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting the performance benefit because you still have to do two memory lookups in your wrappered version. The arithmetic int the 1-d case just accessing element x*1000+y requires only one memory lookup. Your wrappered version returns a pointer which must then be dereferences again, which is the slow part.

Try recasting your wrappered version access as

```
inline double  operator()(int x, int y) const {return data[x*Y + y];}
inline double& operator()(int x, int y) {return data[x*Y + y];}
```

and calling as

```
arr(x,y) = n;
```

I'm surprised that the encapsulated one is any faster than the plain 2-d array, as it can only have more overhead.

EDIT: And now with more looking at the problem I see that your solution in fact does not do two lookups, as your overloaded [] operator behaves differently. See my comment on the original post.

Comment: C++ does not allow differentiating overloads by return-type only. The first one should be a `const` member to address this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you asking why the speed up of using 2D vs 1D seems to be negligible.

The best way to do 2D matrix access in my opinion is using something like the following.

```
double& operator()(const int row, const int col) inline{
    return data[X*row + col];
}

double operator()(const int row, const int col) inline const{
    return data[X*row + col];
}
```

This gives you a reference and a copy method.

The problem with speed is that it is highly dependant on the underlying architecture of your machine.

The first issue is cache size. Obviously the larger the cache the better and the 1D version should work better that the 2D in general as contiguous memory plays better with the cache.

Also in your example accessing a single element for the first time will be slow regardless of how the memory is ordered as the element isn't in the cache. However if you access that element many times, or element in the same area (cache line) the speed up should be more pronounced.

The second issue is vectorization. Depending on the operations you are doing, especially if they are mathematical operations like adding etc, they will determine the speed. If you have a newer processor with SSE or AVX extensions then ensure that the compiler is compiling to use these features, usually this is done automatically when you set optimizations. You may want to make sure though by adding -march=native and -msse3 or the Windows equivalent.

Another small optimization is to make X,Y const. This will make inlining even more effective  but obviously comes with the downside that assigning becomes a pain.

Final word: Profile, see where you spend the most time and improve it.

Comment: The slowdown is certainly due to the 2-d array needing to do two memory lookups, which is far slower than the 1-d arrays 1 (addition and multiplication) and 1 lookup. This method of flattened array you mention here (and I mention below 7 seconds later apparently) gives both the encapsulation and the speedup of using arithmetic.

Comment: @user2711915 I'm not sure I follow how [x][y] requires 2 memory lookups? `data[5]` in terms pointers is just syntactic sugar for `data +  sizeof(data[0])*5` If you expand this with `[x][y]` there are no additional memory accesses as sizeof(data[0]) should be know at compile time. Its just the same arithmetic. Therefore [x][y] is same as I've defined however the compiler generates behind the scenes.

Comment: data[5] IS a memory lookup. In the other case, you go to data[x], find the memory address contained there, X, and then do another lookup to go to X[y]. You don't know where X is until after you have looked at the value contained within data[x]. If data was a constant pointer to constant pointer data (which it never is) then you could in principle have the compiler do this arithmetic for you, but in general it must be a run time lookup.

Comment: @user2711915 Okay, yes. I forgot data[5] itself is a pointer which must be dereferenced in the 2D case.

Comment: @en4bz: good comment on *how* accessing array: in my case its a image processing (Fourier transform and convolution). So its much math and relative same area. but see my edit.

Comment: @mb84 Honestly if you are doing image processing just use openCV, no need to reinvent the wheel. If you can't use openCV for whatever reason it might be valuable to just look at the `cv::Mat` code and see what they do.

Answer (score 0):

The other benefit of the plain one is that dimensions are const, if you do not require runtime dimensions, try using a template:

Also rather than worry about memory management - this will be better suited by using `std::unique_ptr` and instead of `double[]` use `std::array`

```
template <class T, size_t X, size_t Y>
class Array
{
    using custom_array=std::array<T,X*Y>;
    std::unique_ptr<custom_array> data;

public:
    Array() : data{new custom_array} {}
    Array(const Array& rhs) : data{new custom_array(*(rhs.data))} {}
    Array& operator=(const Array& rhs) {
         if (&rhs != this)
         {
            *data=*(rhs.data);
         }
         return *this;
    }
    ~Array() {}
    T& operator() (int x, int y) { return data->at(x*Y+y); }
    T operator() (int x, int y) const { return data->at(x*Y+y); }
};
```

Usage: `Array<double,1000,1000> A; double b=A(3,4);`

For apples to apples - allocate data as `std::array<double,X*Y>`, but since you want heap allocation, use the above with `unique_ptr`.